# Spring Security : link between AuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security

In some Spring Security code, I can see that :

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
}
```

From my understanding, `AuthenticationManager` manages a list of `AuthenticationProvider`
And each `AuthenticationProvider` has its own `UserDetailsService` implementation.

This is what  don't understand with the code above : when writting `auth.userDetailsService(...)`, which `AuthenticationProvider` is used ? Does a new one got created ? Beucause there's a direct link between `AuthenticationManager` and `UserDetailsService`, but nothing about `AuthenticationProvider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);` you are adding a new `DaoAuthenticationProvider` that uses your `UserDetailsService` provided.

More specifically when calling the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder#userDetailsService` method, you are setting the `defaultUserDetailsService` property and applying a configuration of the type `DaoAuthenticationConfigurer`.

This configuration will then add the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` in the list of `AuthenticationProvider` that can be used.

You can find more details in the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` [source code](https://github.com/marcusdacoregio/spring-security/blob/01927323b761a9dbf48ad804506288a1ad3eb575/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.java#L181).